# How to use the same browser window every time you start a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, browser

Does anyone know of a way to set Visual Studio to use the same browser window again, instead of opening a new one, every time you start/debug an ASP.NET project?

This is a simple issue.  When I click 'Start with Debugging' to test my ASP.NET application, it launches my project in a new browser window.

During development at any one point I have nearly a dozen browser windows open, which is not a big deal, but having to open the developer tools and get the browser setup again so I can see what is going on is annoying.

I have looked around for an answer to this, but I did not find anything.

Comment: Thank you for linking that previous question.  I think the real problem is how I am testing a web app in the first place.  I come from the desktop software world, in which you compile, run, and test.  It's obvious to me now that it is important to remember that the browser is more of a 'player', so leaving it open and refreshing   the page after a compile is a better solution.  Additionally, to actually debug, the link to previous question shows how to essentially start a debug session, and continue to use an already open browser.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close the browser window, and next time just BUILD the project, and then go back to the browser and refresh your page... there is a new icon in your tray that shows that the "ASP.NET Development Server" is running, and the project is available in the browser as long as this icon is there.