# Configure Visual Studio or Chrome To Launch Multiple Asp.Net Projects In The Same New Browser Window

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2017 with multiple Asp.Net startup projects.

**Current Behavior**

When I start debugging each project starts in a new Chrome window with a single tab.

**Desired behavior**

When I start debugging all web pages start in the same new Chrome window, each in its own tab.

---

I had the desired behavior in Brave browser, apparently by default—but for business reasons I now need to switch to debugging primarily in Chrome.

So, I suspect this is a browser setting, but as long as I get the desired behavior I am willing to adjust settings in either the browser, Visual Studio or both.

---

**UPDATE**:

To be clear this is not:

- [How to use the same browser window every time you start a project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635119/how-to-use-the-same-browser-window-every-time-you-start-a-project-in-visual-stud)

Nor is it:

- [Stop Visual Studio from launching a new browser window when starting debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716494/stop-visual-studio-from-launching-a-new-browser-window-when-starting-debug)

I do want a new browser window, apart from any previous debugging and indeed a separate instance from any browser I may have already started on the same machine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> To Launch Multiple Asp.Net Projects In The **Same** Browser Window

You can go Tools menu => Options => Project and Solutions => Web Projects, then you can find a setting called:

> **Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops**

[image: Image of mentioned setting]

Uncheck it and click `OK`, then you can start the multiple projects in same Browser Window. Note: This behavior after uncheck that setting may not meet all your needs.It will not open in new Chrome instance but in a `already running` Chrome instance if it exists.

When set the Chrome as default browser in VS. If you've already have a Chrome browser running, start the solution and it will open several tabs in that **existing** Chrome instance. And only when you have **no Chrome instance running**, it will start same new Chrome browser window as you expected. So actually this setting only meet part of your expected behavior I guess.

> To Launch Multiple Asp.Net Projects In The **Same New** Browser Window

It seems only when you have no Chrome instance running, this behavior can be reached. And as far as I know, there's no setting in VS can configure VS to **always** launch Chrome in a new instance with several tabs when start the solution with multiple startup projects.So maybe you can go [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to share your requirement to the Product Team by `Suggest a Feature` option. Hope it makes some help:)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using an open browser you can use Browse with...  if you can give any argument to chrome however arbitrary, it will open a new browser window.  It provides the chrome instance a new "signature" and VS will see the browsers as separate applications.